# Create dataframe from samples of a vector

Tags: r

Assume we have a vector `v <- 1:3` from which we want to generate a dataframe with 5 rows by applying the `sample` function to `v`. The expected results should be something like this:

```
X1  X2  X3
1   3   2
2   3   1
3   1   2
2   1   3
3   2   1
```

Note: It doesn't really matter if some rows are duplicated. I would prefer a solution that doesn't require a forloop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v = 1:3
data.frame(matrix(sample(v, 5*length(v), replace = T), nrow = 5, ncol = length(v)))
#  X1 X2 X3
#1  3  3  1
#2  1  1  3
#3  3  3  1
#4  2  2  1
#5  3  1  2

# else 
data.frame(t(replicate(5, sample(v, length(v), replace = F))))
# else 
data.frame(t(sapply(1:5, function(x) sample(v, length(v), replace = F))))
```

Comment: This is close to the solution but I don't want replicated values *within* each rows. Duplicated rows are OK.

Comment: @mat something like `data.frame(t(sapply(1:5, function(x) sample(v, length(v), replace = F))))` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think `pryr`'s `%<a-%` operator is great for this. `%<a-%` saves an expression to a variable, but every time the variable is evaluated the expression is rerun. Perfect for sampling:

```
library(pryr)
#the function sample will be rerun each time sampled is evaluated
sampled %<a-% sample(v)

#replicate just replicates an expression
#t pivots the matrix, so that you get the output you want
data.frame(t(replicate(5, sampled)))

#or simply (since the edit makes it simpler)
#data.frame(t(replicate(5, sample(v))))
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  3  1  2
2  2  1  3
3  1  3  2
4  2  3  1
5  2  3  1
```

Comment: This is close to the solution but I don't want replicated values *within* each rows. Duplicated rows are OK.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that initially. I updated my answer to reflect the output you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
dfV <- data.frame(v1 = sample(v, 5,replace = TRUE), v2 = sample(v, 5, replace = TRUE), v3 = sample(v, 5, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but imagine if I have to do this for 1000 rows? This would not be very practical...